# Google+ Sign in with JavaScript – callback called twice immediately

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-signin

I'm trying the follow the Google+ guidance to start a Google+ Sign in flow using my own button.

Concerning the callback function, the *gapi.auth.signIn* reference says (quote):

> "A function in the global namespace, which is called when the sign-in button is rendered and also called after a sign-in flow completes."

The Google Sign in dialog appears, asking me to sign in, but the callback is called twice **immediately**, before any interaction is made with the dialog. Both times I get a similar authResult, with error="immediate_failed", error_subtype="access_denied", status.signed_in=false

Why is that?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=googleRender" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<script>
  function googleRender() {  // executed when Google APIs finish loading
    var googleSigninParams = {
      'clientid' : '746836915266-a016a0hu45sfiouq7mqu5ps2fqsc20l4.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      'cookiepolicy' : 'http://civoke.com',
      'callback' : googleSigninCallback ,
      'requestvisibleactions' : 'http://schema.org/AddAction',
      'scope' : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
    };
    var googleSigninButton = document.getElementById('googleSigninButton');
    googleSigninButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      gapi.auth.signIn(googleSigninParams);
    });
  }
  function googleSigninCallback(authResult) {
    console.log('googleSigninCallback called: ');
    console.dir(authResult);
    if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
      document.getElementById('googleSigninButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');  // hide button
      console.log('User is signed-in to Google');
    } else {
      console.log('User is NOT signed-in. Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
    }
  }
</script>

<button id="googleSigninButton">Sign in with Google</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Callback function is called always when the status has changed, not only when user logs in. In `googleSigninCallback(authResult)`, you should at first check if the user has signed in and then you should check, if the method value is `AUTO` or `PROMPT`. `PROMPT` should be returned only once when the users logs in and that's what you need. Here's the code:

```
function googleSigninCallback(authResult) {
  if (authResult['status']['signed_in'] && authResult['status']['method'] == 'PROMPT') {
      // User clicked on the sign in button. Do your staff here.
  } else if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
      // This is called when the status has changed and method is not 'PROMPT'.
  } else {
      // Update the app to reflect a signed out user
      // Possible error values:
      //   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
      //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
      //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
      console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
  }
```

Comment: First of all it works (thanks). Two comments though: (1) When not 'PROMPT' I get null rather than 'AUTO'; (2) This still doesn't explain why it's called **twice** as there are no two immediate status changes...

Comment: I've been tearing my hair out with this one. Thanks.